# Unbinding USB Interface to use Chrome Web USB API

Tags: drivers, usb, google-chrome

How can I unbind an USB interface?

Found multiple pages like this one: [Manual driver binding and unbinding](https://lwn.net/Articles/143397/) or this one: [How to unbind/bind a usb device as normal user?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/798040/how-to-unbind-bind-a-usb-device-as-normal-user)

Which suggest to use the following command:

```
sudo echo -n "1-1:1.0" > /sys/bus/usb/drivers/usb/unbind
```

This gives me the following response:

> echo: write error: No such device

But the folder is available inside my file system:
[image: folder found in file system]

lsusb gives me:

```
Bus 001 Device 047: ID 0483:1234 STMicroelectronics USB2CAN converter
```

and usb-devices:

```
T:  Bus=01 Lev=01 Prnt=01 Port=00 Cnt=01 Dev#= 47 Spd=12  MxCh= 0
D:  Ver= 2.00 Cls=ff(vend.) Sub=ff Prot=00 MxPS=64 #Cfgs=  1
P:  Vendor=0483 ProdID=1234 Rev=01.00
S:  Manufacturer=8Devices
S:  Product=USB2CAN converter
S:  SerialNumber=5D2C531E
C:  #Ifs= 1 Cfg#= 1 Atr=80 MxPwr=100mA
I:  If#=0x0 Alt= 0 #EPs= 4 Cls=ff(vend.) Sub=ff Prot=ff Driver=usb_8dev
```

Also if I try to use ’sudo echo -n "0-1:1.0" > /sys/bus/usb/drivers/usb/unbind’ or ’sudo echo -n "1-0:1.0" > /sys/bus/usb/drivers/usb/unbind’ it gives me:

```
echo: write error: No such device
```

What works is:

```
sudo echo -n "1-1" > /sys/bus/usb/drivers/usb/unbind
```

But if I try to connect like this via Chrome:

```
navigator.usb.requestDevice({ filters: [{}] })
.then(selectedDevice => {
   device = selectedDevice;
console.log(device);
   return device.open()
    .then(() => device.reset())
    .then(() => device.selectConfiguration(1))
    .then(() => device.claimInterface(device.configuration.interfaces[0].interfaceNumber))
 });
```

it still gives me:

> DOMException: Unable to claim interface.

Also unlike this person [How to claim interface using WebUSB?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40996858/how-to-claim-interface-using-webusb) I can select the device.

**tl;dr:**

I would like to connect to an USB device with the [WebUSB API](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2016/03/access-usb-devices-on-the-web) but it's giving me

> DOMException: Unable to claim interface.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So basically you have to do this for "8devices".

```
/sys/bus/usb/drivers/usb_8dev$ echo "1-1:1.0" > unbind
```

in long:

```
cd /sys/bus/usb/drivers/usb_8dev
echo "1-1:1.0" > unbind
```

You will find a file called something similar to "1-1:1.0" in /sys/bus/usb/drivers/usb_8dev so just do a ls to get the correct file and then exchange "1-1:1.0" for this value.

Also don't forget to set `sudo chmod -R -v 777 ./` to the driver(ex. usb_8dev) folder.

Also recommended: [Disconnect and reconnect ttyUSB0 programmatically in Linux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21580750/disconnect-and-reconnect-ttyusb0-programmatically-in-linux)